# How to add metadata to AAC files?

Tags: metadata, aac

I want an app that can add metadata to AAC audio files, I've tried several one but none of them actually detect my audio files in the subfdolder like: Quod Libet, Ex Falso, EasyTAG Audio tag viewer/editor.
Any suggestion?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-05-16, easytag gives nothing but errors on my Ubuntu 22-04 system, failing to write anything.

On the same date, kid3 worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, an appropriately configured and compiled EasyTag has no issues with tagging AAC files as this screenshot demonstrates:

[image]

Observe as well the 'byline' for EasyTag on [its SourceForge site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easytag/):

> EasyTAG is an utility for viewing and editing tags for MP3, MP2, ***MP4/AAC***, FLAC, Ogg Vorbis, MusePack, Monkey's Audio and WavPack files. Its simple and nice GTK+ interface makes tagging easier.